# How to shrink Win10 partition to create partitions for Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, swap, disk-management

[Windows 10 Disk Management Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5ZSN.jpg)

This is a new system. I have just installed Windows 10 + Drivers. Still no data on the SSD.
I need to shrink Partition C to be 50GB so I can create 3 other partitions (Data + Ubuntu + Swap). Windows 10 Disk Management doesn't allow me to shrink the partition to less than ~240GB!!.

How to safely shrink this partitions?

Thank You!

Comment: The screenshot has a hint at the solution: Defrag, then resize using Disk Management.

Comment: @wjandrea.. I tried that and it didn't solve it. This screenshot was taken after the Defargment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easeus partition master is a utility available for Windows which will let you shrink your windows partition upto the free space you have in it.

It comes in free as well as paid option, for your situation free option will work

[EasyUS Partition Manager](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/)

at some point you'll need to do the same in Ubuntu, that's where [GParted](http://gparted.org/download.php) comes in

run following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```